# How can I show the Alert button?

Tags: android

i can not see my button....it just show a Message....pleas help me....

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("delete?");
        builder.create().show();
        builder.setPositiveButton("yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton("no",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Please elaborate your problem to make it more understandable

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are creating `AlertDialog` before and then setting buttons to `AlertDialog`. try below code

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("delete?");       
builder.setPositiveButton("yes",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
     });
     builder.setNegativeButton("no",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
     });
builder.create().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create the dialog before the setting.

Move below codes to the end of your existing codes

```
builder.create().show();
```

Final codes will look as below:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("delete?");       
    builder.setPositiveButton("yes",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            
        }
        
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("no",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            
        }
        
    });
    
    builder.create().show();    //this is the line that has been moved
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call `builder.setPositiveButton` before create `AlertDialogBuilder`.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("delete?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton("no",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });

       builder.create().show();
```